# Prove $2^{2m}-2^m+1 \equiv 3 \pmod 9$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How can I get $2^{2m}-2^m+1 \equiv 3  \pmod 9$ when $m$ is an odd integer?

Comment: List out the congruence results modulo $9$ for the exponents $m=0,1,2,\dots,8$.  It should repeat since the order will be less than $9$.  This proves the result.  Alternatively, add $4^{-1}-1$ to both sides to get $2^{2m}-2^m+4^{-1}\equiv 2+4^{-1}\pmod 9\to (2^m-2^{-1})^2\equiv 2+(-2)\pmod 9$ which then becomes $(2^m+4)^2\equiv 0\pmod 9$.

Comment: @ChristianF: I really like the $m=2n+1$ trick and how it works out... why did you delete your answer?

Comment: @abiessu I thought I was wrong for a moment....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x= 2^m$ and $m=2n+1$.

$$2^{2m}-2^m-2 = x^2-x-2 = (x-2)(x+1) = (2^m+1)(2^m-2)$$

Since $$2^m+1 = (2+1)(2^{m-1}+...+2^2+2+1) =3a$$

and $$2^m-2= 2(4^n-1) = 2(4-1)(4^{n-1}+...+4^2+4+1) =3b$$

we are done.

Comment: Once you have the first one of these, the second factor differs by $3$ from the first

Answer (score 1):

If $m$ is an odd integer then $2^m = 2, 5 \text{ or } 8 \mod 9$ so you only need to check 3 cases.